# Getting Null exception while downloading PDF file stored in MySQL database in Blob format or Binary

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Hi I'm trying to download PDF file stored in MySQL database in Blob format or Binary and I'm getting Null exception on do.GET 
HERE is My Code
and 
Stack Trace`

```
enter code here


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/downloadFileServlet")
public class DBFileDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // size of byte buffer to send file
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;    

// database connection settings
private String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private String dbUser = "root";
private String dbPass = "secret";

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // get upload id from URL's parameters
    int uploadId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    Connection conn = null; // connection to the database

    try {
        // connects to the database
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","ROOT");

        // queries the database
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM files_upload WHERE upload_id = ?";
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setInt(1, uploadId);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            // gets file name and file blob data
            String fileName = result.getString("file_name");
            Blob blob = result.getBlob("file_data");
            InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
            int fileLength = inputStream.available();

            System.out.println("fileLength = " + fileLength);

            ServletContext context = getServletContext();

            // sets MIME type for the file download
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
            if (mimeType == null) {         
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }               

            // set content properties and header attributes for the response
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength(fileLength);
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

            // writes the file to the client
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outStream.close();              
        } else {
            // no file found
            response.getWriter().print("File not found for the id: " + uploadId);   
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        response.getWriter().print("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        response.getWriter().print("IO Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            // closes the database connection
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

}

```
     SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Download] in context with path           [/Download111] threw exception
     java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
     at Download.doGet(Download.java:42)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
     at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
     at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please Help..

if i change the int parse to string I'm getting http 500 error of httpmaxheadersize i cant retrieve a PDFs stored in MySQL dB

Comment: post your html/jsp code

Comment: Which line on your code is "line 42"? The exception refers to that line.

Comment: int uploadId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

Comment: check your jsp file the "id" is exist or not and post your jsp code

Comment: There is no element in the name  "id "change  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("BookId"));

Comment: SQL Error: Column 'file_name' not found.

Comment: did you check database table for column name

Comment: BookId and BookContent are two column names

Comment: Thanks dude its working

Comment: your table  files_upload contains BookId and BookContent column is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you jsp file there is no element named in "id" so change  `Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")); to  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("BookId"));`